# Understanding a projection function from S to B.

Tags: proof-explanation

Let A and B be sets and $S \subseteq A \times B $ . Let $\pi_{1}$ be the projection function on $S$ to $A$ and $\pi_{2}$ be the projection function on $S$ to $B$. Give an example to show that.

> $\pi_{2}$ need not be onto $B.$

Proof:

Let $A = \Bbb R, B = \Bbb R,S = \{(x,y) \in \Bbb R \times \Bbb R ,y=x^2 \}$

Then $\; y \ge 0$.

Would this not be onto because$ y = x,$ and $y=-x$. Then would it not be a proper mapping?

Comment: I don't quite understand the question. Can't you just take $S = \varnothing$ or similar?

Comment: why would S be an empty set?

Comment: Why not? You just have to give an example.

Comment: So would that be answer that is not onto?

Comment: You already got an answer to your question in the answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The projection is always well defined (a proper mapping). It is not clear what "it" is in your last statement, but no, what you are writing has nothing to do with it. $\pi_2$ is not onto because none of the negative values in $B$ are in the image of S.

A much simpler example: take any $A$, a non-empty $B$, and $S$ be the empty subset of $A \times B$. The projection restricted to $S$ has empty image, so it cannot be onto.

Comment: So to show this symbolically. Let $A \land \; B = \text{nonempty} $              $S = \emptyset$

Comment: Why do you need to show it symbolically? What does that add to anything? Also, $A \ne \emptyset$ is not required.

Comment: I am trying to visualize it.